# Converting a Series of dicts to a drameframe with columns as the dict keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
>>> type(required_data)

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> required_data

0      {u'duration': 79, u'startDate': u'2019-01-02T23:04:15Z',u'endDate': u'2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'}

1      {u'duration': 79, u'startDate': u'2019-01-02T23:04:15Z',u'endDate': u'2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'}

2      {u'duration': 79, u'startDate': u'2019-01-02T23:04:15Z',u'endDate': u'2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'}

3      {u'duration': 79, u'startDate': u'2019-01-02T23:04:15Z',u'endDate': u'2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'}
```

now I want to convert this to a dataframe of the below format

```
    startDate               endDate                 duration
0   '2019-01-02T23:04:15Z'  '2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'  79
1   '2019-01-02T23:04:15Z'  '2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'  79
2   '2019-01-02T23:04:15Z'  '2019-01-02T23:05:35Z'  79
```

I have tried like below

created a empty dataframe

```
required_df = pd.DataFrame()
required_data.apply(lambda x:required_df.append(x,ignore_index=True))
```

It is not giving the desired results. Pleas help.

Comment: I suppose it's not giving the desired results?

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame(required_data.to_list())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame(list(requeired_data.values))`. It then gives a clean DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(requeired_data.values))
   duration               endDate             startDate
0        79  2019-01-02T23:05:35Z  2019-01-02T23:04:15Z
1        79  2019-01-02T23:05:35Z  2019-01-02T23:04:15Z
2        79  2019-01-02T23:05:35Z  2019-01-02T23:04:15Z
3        79  2019-01-02T23:05:35Z  2019-01-02T23:04:15Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Series` is basically a list of dict. Convert it to a proper list using `to_list()` and instantiating a DataFrame seems enough.

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([{'duration' : 'hello', 'value' : 'world'}, {'duration' : 'hello', 'value' : 'world'}, {'duration' : 'hello', 'value' : 'world'}])
print(ser)
# 0    {'duration': 'hello', 'value': 'world'}
# 1    {'duration': 'hello', 'value': 'world'}
# 2    {'duration': 'hello', 'value': 'world'}
# dtype: object

df = pd.DataFrame(ser.to_list())
print(df)
#   duration  value
# 0    hello  world
# 1    hello  world
# 2    hello  world
```